# Rest API POST METHOD ||| ISSUE Exception :Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, rest

1. List item

I'm building a Flutter Front End For An Existing ASP.net MVC Project. I Have Created A New API project To My Existing Solution And Added controllers And I didn't create separate models or view model for my API
project ,I just added project reference from my existing MVC project So that I can Use The same Models and view models. But the problem is the following:-
My Repo....

```html
public class UserLoginRepo : IUserLogin
    {
        private readonly CADbContext _context;
        private readonly CaIdentityDbContext _ctx;
        private readonly UserManager<MembershipUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<MembershipUser> _signInManager;

        public UserLoginRepo(CADbContext context, UserManager<MembershipUser> userManager, SignInManager<MembershipUser> signInManager, CaIdentityDbContext ctx)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _ctx = ctx;
        }

        public bool CompanyCodeLogin(String user)
        {
            Company c;
            if (user != null)
            {
                c = _context.Companies.Where(x => x.CompanyCode == user).SingleOrDefault();
                if (c != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;

                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

This is actually The POST methods Inside My  Controller:-

```
        public async Task<bool> VerifyCompanyCodek(string companyCode)
        {
            var result = await _userLogin.VerifyCompanyCode(companyCode);
            return result;
        }
        [HttpPost("VerifyLogin")]
        public async Task<bool> VerifyLogin([FromBody]LoginViewModel model)
        {
            return await _userLogin.VerifyLogin(model);
        }
```

the First Method does work on verifying the Company Code. But Sadly The Verify Login Post Method Throws the exception. when I checked I was Able to find out that the _userManager(UserManager ) inside the constructor isn't getting the values. **I'm using the same connection String used for my web application and it works fine for it's Log In Controller.** The same String value is being are being passed to the FindByNameAsync() method.

**Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.**

this exception is always thrown when **I'm using usermanager's FindByNameAsync() to check whether there exist a user having the user name in order to provide Authentication for my user's Log In.** But Unfortunately I can't understand why it throws this exception.I have triple checked my connection string I really hope that you experts can shed some light on this problem...

```html
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CADbContext": "Server=server_name;Database=database;User Id=id;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",
    "CaIdentityDbContext": "Server=server_name;Database=database;User Id=id;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"

}
```

Comment: If you can share your connection string (please remove or hide userid, pwd etc information if it includes) used in your application, then we can help check it.

Comment: `{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CADbContext": "Server=server_name;Database=database;User Id=id;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",
    "CaIdentityDbContext": "Server=server_name;Database=database;User Id=id;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"

}`      @FeiHan